# img float:left - margin elements on the right

Tags: html, css

As you can see in this example http://jsfiddle.net/PCcj8/ I'd like to add some margin to my unordered list. However, I'm not able to move that list because of that img float. How can I achieve it? Please consider there can be different images of different widths.

Comment: Can I adjust the fiddle? I've got an idea, but don't know how it would work (making that UL display: inline-block, and putting back just a touch of the left margin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `<ul>` tag in a `<span>` tag `<span>` tag like this:

```
<span>
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

and then style the span like this:

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;    
}
```

Comment: Just remember `inline-block` isn't fully supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

New style definition for that UL:

ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px; display: inline-block; 
}

It leaves a LITTLE bit of an indent for the line item, and it will move along with any images you may put to the side.

Here's a forked fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/99a2L/2/)

Comment: Just remember `inline-block` isn't fully supported in older browsers.